# Play Framework: Images not accessible in production, despite trying the "route + custom action" solution

Tags: java, playframework, angular2-routing, assets, production-environment

We have a web application comprising a client in Angular2 and a server in Play Framework 2.6. This application should allow users to upload their own images. Similarly to many users here, we faced the problem of not being able to access the images in `public/assets` in production mode, and so we tried the solutions that have been provided to those users, with no success.

We created the following route in the `conf/routes` file:

```
GET         /files/*file                                    controllers.AdminExerciseCtrl.serve(file)
```

leading to the following custom action:

```
public Result serve(String file) {

    Boolean DEVELOPMENT = Boolean.parseBoolean(ConfigFactory.load().getString("development"));
    String path;

    if(DEVELOPMENT) path = "public/";             
    else path = ConfigFactory.load().getString("root/");

    return ok(new java.io.File(path + file));
}
```

i.e., we are saving the uploaded images to `root/files/images`.

We tried two way of accessing this route:

1. Using `@routes` throws an error because of the @ character
2. Using the route in the `src` field (where `resource.resourcePath` is a variable holding the path to the image file, e.g., `images/pic.jpg`), the route simply isn't found (404).
   `<img *ngIf="resource" class="thumbnail" [src]="'/files/' + resource.resourcePath">`

We are starting to despair since this project is considerably large and uploading images is a core feature. Any ideas of what we could be missing? Anything we should be doing in the client regarding the routes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So this is working in dev mode, but not prod mode? Can you share an example of a rendered `<img>` tag from your application in both modes?

Comment: Hello Rich. This approach is not working in both modes. 

An example of an image was intended to be in the original post but only now I realized that it somehow did not render to the final post. I fixed the post now.

Comment: That looks like Angular syntax - can you give the actual rendered HTML?